# Responsive menu issue disable full view

Tags: jquery, html, css

Solved: Answer solved by Riddler

Update: New Issue:

Everthing is working fine but the menu is visible in screen 1368 and I want to show the menu only in 768 or 1024 or any screen size lower.

---

Actually I embedded a menu in my website and its working fine but i want to make a minor change in the menu.

As i wanted to disable the full view and just want to have the mobile view only means responsive design, but i tried using the display:hide,,, i didn't worked..

please help.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="eos-menu" id="menu">
            <div class="eos-menu-title">Welcome to eosMenu Plugin<i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg eos-pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <div class="eos-menu-content">
                <li class="eos-item">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> Home</a>
                </li>
                <div class="eos-group-title"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> Contact Us</div>
                <div class="eos-group-title"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> Profile <i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-lg eos-pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                <div class="eos-group-content">
                    <li class="eos-item">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> New User</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="eos-item">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i> All Users</a>
                    </li>
                </div>
                <li class="eos-item">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear" aria-hidden="true"></i> Settings</a>
                </li>
                <div class="eos-group-title"><i class="fa fa-share" aria-hidden="true"></i> Social Media <i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-lg eos-pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                <div class="eos-group-content">
                    <li class="eos-item">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i> Facebook</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="eos-item">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i> Twitter</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="eos-item">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Google Plus</a>
                    </li>
                </div>

                <li class="eos-item">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-power-off" aria-hidden="true"></i> Logout</a>
                </li>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.eos-menu, .eos-menu *, .eos-menu *:before, .eos-menu *:after {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}

.eos-menu {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #eee;
}

.eos-menu li {
    list-style: none;
}

.eos-menu .eos-menu-content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    height: 0px;
    z-index: 10;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.eos-menu .eos-group-content {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    height: 0px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.eos-menu .eos-menu-title,
.eos-menu .eos-group-title,
.eos-menu .eos-item {
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    background: #2F4050;
    border-color: #293744;
    padding-left: 15px !important;
    padding-right: 15px !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

.eos-menu .eos-menu-title .fa,
.eos-menu .eos-group-title .fa,
.eos-menu .eos-item .fa {
    line-height: 40px;
}

.eos-menu .eos-menu-title:hover,
.eos-menu .eos-group-title:hover,
.eos-menu .eos-item:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #293744;
}

.eos-menu .eos-group-content .eos-item {
    background: #263442;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
}

.eos-menu .eos-item a {
    color: #eee;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.eos-menu .eos-pull-right {
    float: right;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .eos-menu .eos-menu-title {
        display: none;
    }
    .eos-menu .eos-menu-content {
        height: auto;
        position: inherit;
    }
}
```

javascript: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-Collapsible-Toggle-Menu-Plugin-With-jQuery-eosMenu/eosMenu/eosMenu.js

Demo: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-Collapsible-Toggle-Menu-Plugin-With-jQuery-eosMenu/

More Info: http://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Responsive-Collapsible-Toggle-Menu-Plugin-With-jQuery-eosMenu.html

Thanks

Comment: And use proper english please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update answer:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
        .eos-menu {
            display: none;
        }            
    }
```

Comment: it worked fine and displaying mobile menu but problem is its showing mobile menu on media screen 1368.. how to only enable menu on 1024 or any other media screen.

BTW thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Then don't delete the code, change the value 768px to 1024px

Comment: Thanks bro.. but problem is still there... I mean I want to hide the whole menu on media screen 1368 and want to activate only on 1024 or anything.

Comment: God you are changing requirements faster than clients do, I cannot update my answer based on your comments, Change the question and then i can tell you.

Comment: I understand its hard to answer everything and its irritating. But I am new into this brother.

question edited 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mobile menu only to view on mobile so use if condition.

```
var windowwidth = $(window).width();
if ((windowwidth < 767)) {
    $("#menu").eosMenu();
};

@media only screen and(max-width:767px){
     write css for mobile
}
```